# what is a difference between "forward" in web.xml from one in the filter

Tags: java, filter, spring-security

what exactly doing

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>  
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

when forward has existed in filter&

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that this filter is also applied to internally forwarded requests (not just to the original incoming requests from outside).

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance, but would you explain it more explicidly

Comment: When you forward to another page (`getRequestDispatcher("template.jsp").forward(req,resp)`), then usually, no filters run on that internal request. With this option, you can add filters here as well.

Comment: You want to say that forwarding to template.jsp I can include filter to this request ? I met doFilterInternal its something from this field?